Solve equation knowing variables possible values
With an equation like this:
(1.93*A + 1.93) + (0.24*B + 0.24) + (0.16*C + 0.16) = 26.77

I want to solve the equation, knowing that A, B and C could take a value from the following intervals or 0:
[24.00, 26.00] 
[19.00, 21.00] 
[9.00, 11.00] 
[4.60, 4.90] 
I tried with MathNet:
double[] coeficients = { 1.93, 0.24, 0.16 };
double total = 26.77;

var objFunction = ObjectiveFunction.Value(x =>
{
    double res = total -
    (coeficients[0] * x[0] + coeficients[0]) -
    (coeficients[1] * x[1] + coeficients[1]) -
    (coeficients[2] * x[2] + coeficients[2]);

    return res * res;
});

var optimizer = new NelderMeadSimplex(1e-9, 1000000);
var optimization = optimizer.FindMinimum(objFunction, Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(new double[] { 5, 5, 5 }));

Console.WriteLine("Optimization :");
Console.WriteLine($"A: {optimization .MinimizingPoint[0]}");
Console.WriteLine($"B: {optimization .MinimizingPoint[1]}");
Console.WriteLine($"C: {optimization .MinimizingPoint[2]}");
Console.WriteLine($"Exit For: {optimization .ReasonForExit}");

This is what I get on my output:
A: 11,753698738817143
B: 6,016323876437925
C: 1,9465231487666925
Exit For: Converged

But the values I get are out of my intervals. I'm looking for something like this instead:
A: 10,010362694300518134715025906736
B: 4,7916666666666666666666666666667
C: 24,8125


@MakePeaceGreatAgain What I mean is that I'm searching for a way to implement (or if there is any already implemented in c#) to solve the described equation. That I have already explored AngouriMath and MathNet and I have not been able to codify the problem with those two solutions.

@Fildor, yes, the .99 values are included. Edited question for clarification

Ok, so you have an intentional gap between 4.99 and 5.00, understood.

What are you expecting as solution? It's probably going to be a whole set of possible solutions. Are there any additional requirements, like a "minimal" solution or something like that?

@Filidor, Updated question with what I tried and why it's not working

What kind of results are needed? The equation could have countless solutions.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain My lambda is a Minimum function. So what I'm aiming to do with that is to generate values to get close to 0 after substracting from the total

@shingo there seems to be some optimization that indicates one single solutionn.

You should definitly add this to your question. This is relevant.

Why don't you write your equation as 1.93*(A+1) + 0.24*(B+1) + 0.16*(C+1) = 26.77? That's far more readable. In top of that, you can shift your intervals accordingly (instead of working with A in [24.00, 26.00], you just have A+1 in [25.00, 27.00]).

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I meant the possible values of A,B,C can be countless, this is not hard to prove.

besides the points raised by others about this having multiple (actually infinite) solutions, you  do not specifiy the allowed intervals anywhere. I don't have a real solution for that. You could perhaps work with a penalty within your objFunction whenever a value is outside the allowed intervals.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I think you are misunderstanding the code OP posted. The objFunction is just a transformation of the original formula. (26.77 - (1.93*A + 1.93) - (0.24*B + 0.24) - (0.16*C + 0.16))^2 should be minimized (converge to zero). There are still an infinite amount of solutions.

@JeanotZubler Aaah, indeed, you're right - despite the square.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain The square is probably just there to keep the error positive. It might even help a faster converging, as larger errors get magnified even more.
